# Add a CQL Filter to a WMS Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, cql-filter, cql

I have a WMS Layer published by a geoserver instance. It has the capability of being filtered by a CQL Filter via GetMap CQL_FILTER query parameter.

Adding it to QGIS works, but I can't find a place to add a CQL Filter in QGIS.

There is an old issue about it: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/15626

Is there any progress on the theme or a work around?

QGIS is version 3.10.4 - but I'm willing to change it if it solves my problem

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to work around this issue.

As the WMS layer is added, type the cql filter into the address/URL place and select in the options to ignore GetMap/GetTile URI reported in capabilities.

Comment: YES! Thank you! This also works for `viewparams` parameters, not just CQL queries. See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418516/12587

Comment: Assumes that the GetCapabilities and GetMap/GetTile are served from the same service URL, which isn't always the case