# How can I control a custom parameter in QGIS WMS/WMTS/WFS webservices

Tags: qgis, geoserver, qgis-plugins, ows

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) layers can be configured to be very flexible with parameters in at least these two ways:

- viewparams pass through to the SQL view ([link](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#parameterizing-sql-views))
- time/elevation/custom dimension ([link](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#data-webadmin-layers-edit-dimensions) and [link](https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/vector/index.html))

A sample call would look something like: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Atasmania_cities&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=641&BBOX=145.9588623046875%2C-43.378143310546875%2C148.0682373046875%2C-41.617584228515625&time=2012-10-13T00:00:00.000Z&elevation=1233.47&viewparams=low:20000000 (note: `time` & `elevation` & `viewparams=low`)

In a JavaScript client like [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), it is easy to add these additional parameters to the WMS request.

In QGIS, it is possible to use the Time Manager (up to v3.12) or the [Temporal Controller](https://anitagraser.com/2020/05/10/timemanager-is-dead-long-live-the-temporal-controller/) (after v3.12) to manipulate the time parameter (but the time parameter must be in the correct ISO8601 timestamp format, so can't be used for general parameters)

---

However, I cannot find another QGIS plugin that allows a user to manipulate any dimension (e.g. `elevation` or the `low` viewparam above) with a slider or similar control.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If not, is this something useful that I should consider implementing as a plugin?

I assume that I should be able to intercept the WMS/WMTS/WFS webservice requests when they are created, modify the parameters and forward them on.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would also like to use Time enabled GeoServer WMTS and WMS layer in QGIS.

Answer (score 5):

It's astonishing to me that this is still unresolved. Fortunately, based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389958/12587) I found a workaround.

While adding the WMS layer in QGIS, you need to manually append your parameters to the URL. In my case, that meant my URL ended with `.../wms?viewparams=foo:bar`.

After this, the critical step was to **check the box to "Ignore GetMap/GetTile/GetLegendGraphic URI reported in capabilities"**.

[image: QGIS Desktop screenshot - Ignore URI reported in capabilities]

Doing so caused my layers to load properly when using `viewparams`, and I'm pretty sure this will work in the case of time/elevation/CQL queries, too.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a slider or other control to set the viewparam foo to bar1, bar2.. bar10, etc

Comment: Just tried this and the layer loaded fine, respecting the parameter. But if I do a query on the layer (Identify features tool in QGis), the result will not respect the parameter set. So I suspect the parameter is not passed to getFeatureInfo.